# SQL Server, View Returns no rows, except for sa Account

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Microsoft Dynamics database on-prem and I am going through the filtered views, if I query the views as any user aside from the sa account, I get 0 rows returned.  I have a login that is mapped to the database as db_owner, I can see the database, tables, views, edit stored procs, etc.  But if I select the top 100 rows I get 0 rows returned.

Any suggestions?

1. Assigned db_owner, db_datareeader, db_datawriter
2. Tried other logins